# SAS: Stacking CSV Files with blank observations

Tags: csv, import, sas

I have worked with coworkers on this, googled around, edited this code a million times and I cannot get it to work.

Essentially, I am trying to stack multiple CSV files into one SAS dataset.  I created earlier in my SAS the ability to find all of the names of the files [variable *fname* inside *dirlist1*].  I've been trying to get this code to work but the problem is some of the observations within these CSV files are blank.  So for example column "apples" (see below) will have a majority of the column blank - but will occasionally have data.  Right now this code reads in the right data, but when an observation is blank (e.g. for an observation, "apples" is blank - it shifts my data to the left instead of leaving that part blank.  Is there something I am missing in this current code that can solve that?

Basically it's skipping texttext,text,,text, text < it's skipping that blank between the commas and continuing on and I WANT that blank.

```
data all_data (drop=fname);
  length bananas $256;
  length apples $25;
  length grapefruit $10;
  length berries $10;
set dirlist1;
filepath = "&dirname"||fname;
infile dummy filevar = filepath length=reclen firstobs=2 dlm=',' end=done missover;
do while(not done);
  myfilename = fname;
  input bananas apples grapefruit berries;
output;
  end;
 run;
```

Edit:
To note, I based this code from code published on a UCLA based site [1](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/multi_file_read.htm)

Comment: FYI, `observation` refers to rows, `variables` or `columns` is what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `DSD` modifier to your infile statement.

```
infile dummy filevar = filepath length=reclen firstobs=2 dlm=',' end=done missover DSD;
```

That will tell it to change the default treatment of consecutive delimiters (and also allows it to correctly handle quoted fields with embedded delimiters).

See [the documentation on INFILE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much Joe - this worked like a charm.  This has been causing me a headache for the entire day and you saved it :)  Thank you thank you